# .htaccess Error 404 on index file

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

Good day,

I was wondering if you could help me.
I have a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://scytech.co.za/Page-Not-Found/404
```

When i try to open http://admin.scytech.co.za it give me an error 404 but when i try to open http://admin.scytech.co.za/index it works 100%
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: try putting in under RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]